# paste0() function change decimals digits

Tags: r

`R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)`, `OS Ubuntu 14.04`
Recently I have encountered a very strange problem which is really annoying.

Code:

```
q[94]
# [1] -0.7
paste0(q[94],".dat")
# [1] "-0.699999999999999.dat"
paste0(-0.7,".dat")
# [1] "-0.7.dat"
```

The `paste0` function just change `-0.7` to `-0.699999999999999`. 
This problem does not only happen  at `q[94]` but also with the other 
elements in variable `q`(not all of them). But I can not figure out any patterns in this
problem. And in this case the decimals digits change is not random at different trail. The `-0.7` will always be changed to `-0.699999999999999`. And I have suspected that the problem is related to the `options("digits"=)`, but I have tried to change this option, without any help. Another thing is this problem also happens at my server on which I am using `Cent Os 4.5` with `R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)`.

Update: I have tried `paste0(as.character(q[94]),".dat")`, but it's not work. Even I use `as.character(q)` to convert the entire vector to character vector, this problem also happens.

Edit for clarify: The answers in this question [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal?lq=1) have given good explanations about the the floating point number. What I want to do here is just convert the numeric number to 
a character string as what I see without any unexpected results. So if
I use `paste0()` function what I should do?

Update: The best solution is use `sprintf()` function to control the digits of floating point number

Comment: Try `paste0(as.character(q[94]), ".dat")`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, still with the same problem.

Comment: Use `format` or `sprintf` to transform your floating point numbers to the desired character format before you use `paste0`.

Comment: @Roland Yes, this is exactly what I do now. I haven't come to this problem until now. It is really a lesson. Thanks!